# Extracting sign of scaling from modelView matrix

Tags: matrices, transformation, homogeneous-spaces

I want to retrieve the sign of scaling for each axis from modelview matrix. Right now I am able to extract the sign only if all 3 signs are same but it fails when one of them is different. Here is the example I am trying:

```
float []mat={0.032254f, 0.000000f, 0.000000f, 0.000000f, 0.000000f, -0.0052254f, 0.000000f, 0.000000f, 0.000000f, 0.000000f, 0.4332254f, 0.000000f, 0.000000f, 0.000000f, 0.000000f, 1.000000f};
```

The code is:

```
glm::vec3 Xaxis(matrix[0][0],matrix[0][1],matrix[0][2]);
glm::vec3 Yaxis(matrix[1][0],matrix[1][1],matrix[1][2]);
glm::vec3 Zaxis(matrix[2][0],matrix[2][1],matrix[2][2]);

double zs=glm::dot(glm::cross(Xaxis,Yaxis),Zaxis);
double ys=glm::dot(glm::cross(Zaxis,Xaxis),Yaxis);
double xs=glm::dot(glm::cross(Yaxis,Zaxis),Xaxis);


xs=std::signbit(xs);
ys=std::signbit(ys);
zs=std::signbit(zs);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use
$$
s_i = \text{sgn}(m_{ii})
\quad (i \in \{1,2,3\}) \quad (*)
$$
if $M=(m_{ij})$ is a [scaling matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scaling_(geometry)#Using_homogeneous_coordinates).

If your matrix is 
$$
M =
\left(
\begin{array}{rrrr}
R_{11} S_1 & R_{12} S_2 & R_{13} S_3 & T_1 \\
R_{21} S_1 & R_{22} S_2 & R_{23} S_3 & T_2 \\
R_{31} S_1 & R_{32} S_2 & R_{33} S_3 & T_3 \\
0 & 0 & 0 &  1
\end{array}
\right)
$$
then try
$$
S_i = \sqrt{(M^T M)_{ii}}
$$
first. And then use $S_i$ instead of $m_ii$ in $(*)$.

Comment: can you please explain your answer. what is "sgn" ? And my modelview matrix will be having rotation as well.

Comment: @debonair It is the signum function ([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_%28mathematics%29#Sign_function)).

Comment: so you mean just take the sign of m11, m22 or m33 ? what if it has rotation matrix involved?

Comment: for removing rotation, you need scale.. so scale should be removed first